# How can i fix getting kernel panic after running a update?

Tags: kernel, updates

currently running ubuntu 18.04 ran the command `sudo apt full-upgrade` and tried rebooted the system but after i selected my ubuntu install on the grub menu kept getting something saying something about kernel panic and wont go past that screen?

Comment: This happened after a full upgrade and there was a kernel update recently. Have you tried booting from an older kernel? Select "advanced options" and then select an older kernel from the menu. Please let us know what happens. Thanks!

Comment: got into the desktop had to run repair filesystem from disk utility on a live usb

Comment: Awesome. You can post this as an answer below to help others with the same issue. Then, you can mark this as the accepted solution after a couple of days to give others a chance to answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got into the desktop had to run repair filesystem from disk utility on a live usb